# Azure DevOps ignores the Publish of one project

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0

On Azure DevOps Pipelines I have task to Build an Asp.Net Core application:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

With Output:

```
Restoring packages for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Api/Api.csproj...
Restoring packages for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Core/Core.csproj...
Restore completed in 672.27 ms for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Core/Core.csproj.
Restore completed in 676.4 ms for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Api/Api.csproj.

Core -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Core/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/Core.dll
Api -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Api/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/Api.dll

Build succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
```

Then I added a Publish task:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true
```

With output:

```
Restore completed in 54.68 ms for /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Core/Core.csproj.     
Core -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/src/Core/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/Core.dll
Core -> /home/vsts/work/1/a/.
```

Both tasks run fine but task Publish does not Publish the Api project.

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `publishWebProjects` flag?

Comment: Yes, and then I got an error saying it could not found web projects as it could not find wwwroot or web.config. The API in net core does not have any. The web.config is created during publishing

Comment: Ah sure, just wanted to see if you got that. The build output doesn't seem to build anything, or you just omitted it?. Are you sure that it's finding the `csproj` files? Also, you can just build the API project. The other project it references will be built as part of it.

Comment: Yes, it seems it builds as in the end it says "Build succeeded. 0 Warning(s). 0 Error(s)" ... I just updated my answer ... I have no idea why Publish does not pick the resulting files.

Comment: Wait a second... you have to tell the `publish` step which project to publish. From the output it seems it's publising the `Core` project. Make sure you are either in the same folder or pass the correct project: `projects: '**/MyProject.csproj'`. I was on the phone and miss this yesterday.