# Azure Devops Pipelines dotnet publish task ignores projects setting

Tags: .net, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repo with a couple of dotnet projects, two of them web projects, and I need to specify which to publish.

My yaml file is:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: '**/Squil.Web.csproj'
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: web'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Something similar worked as long as I had only one web project, but after factoring out most Blazor related stuff into another project `Squil.Razor`, it no longer does: The publish task always picks that one, which is a Razor Class Library.

I also tried to use `'Squil.Web'` as the `projects` parameter, but no matter what I put there, it gets ignored.

I've been pulling my hair out over this for hours now. I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615189/azure-devops-ignores-the-publish-of-one-project) from which I got the syntax `'**/Squil.Web.csproj'`, but that didn't work for me either.

I know I can use the dotnet command line instead, but I'd rather use the task.

This is .NET 6.

What else to try?

Answer (score 6):

I found what's wrong.

Unless `publishWebProjects: false` is explicitly specified `projects` is ignored.

Not the best defaults in my book.

Comment: 5 hours. 5 hours it took for me to come across this and fix the issue! Back and forth with ChatGPT and it had no clue. Really wasn't clear that this property was true by default. really frustrating but thanks for the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Worked on mine even with `publishWebProjects` being set to **false**, but projects are still included.

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: |
      **/Sample.Web.Customer.csproj
      **/Sample.Web.Admin.csproj
      **/Sample.ServiceBus.csproj
    arguments: "--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --no-build"
    zipAfterPublish: True
```